# Where to fill message of auth.failed in invalid login?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8  app with fortify on invalid login I get error

```
auth.failed
```

in email error block.
I checked and added line in resources/lang/en/auth.php, but it did not help.
Where have I to add error message?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The LoginController only uses the 2 messages found in the translation file **resources/lang/en/auth.php**

```
'failed' => 'These credentials do not match our records.',
'throttle' => 'Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds.',
```

So you'd need to change it there.

If you look at the AuthController, you'll see it uses the AuthenticatesUsers trait. If you look in that trait, you'll see

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
```

which is where it's loading the auth.failed message from.

Comment: In my project I do not have LoginController or AuthController. Also I do not have AuthenticatesUsers trait. But I have app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php and app/Actions/Fortify/PasswordValidationRules.php files